# How to connect to a root directory with FTP .net WinSCP C#

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I have an application that can perform FTP/SFTP connections but I'm having issues with something, all this time I've been tested it using a remote directory that I knew, but for now I want to get connected to a server to the root directory if I don't know the remote directory.

What it does is:

```
if (RemoteDirectoryPath != "Home")
    RemoteDirectory  = MySession.ListDirectory(RemoteDirectoryPath);
else
    RemoteDirectory = MySession.ListDirectory("/");
```

As you can see in my code above, if the directory is different from Home it will list directory "/", today I was receiving an error that "/" does not exist, even when I did an ftp connection with cmd and then pwd, it was telling me that remote directory was "/"

How can I list directory without use `RemoteDirectory = MySession.ListDirectory("/");` and have someting like `RemoteDirectory = MySession.ListDirectory(Root.Directory);`

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to get the path!

`RemoteDirectory = MySession.ListDirectory(MySession.HomePath);`